# Define PHP Variable with 2 Get Requests

Tags: php

Noob question that is simple but racking my brain and searching the manual to figure out. What is the proper way to do the following...

```
$kw = $_GET['kq'];
$kw = $_GET['kw'];

echo $kw;
```

Thanks in advance for your help here.

Comment: Create a new associative array (just like $_GET itself)

Comment: Are you trying the values to an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either concatenate the two variables like

```
$kw = $_GET['kq'] . $_GET['kw'];
```

Or use an associative array (much like `$_GET` itself)

```
$kw = array('kq' => $_GET['kq'], 'kw' => $_GET['kw']);
echo $kw['kq'];
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate that @Divij Bindlish